# How can I embed an iframe with HTTP URL into Blogger

Tags: http, iframe, embed, blogger, blogspot

I'm trying to embed an iframe into my blogger site. But the main problem is that Blogspot does not support iframe with HTTP URL and my target website is on HTTP.
this is my iframe example:

```html
<iframe
    src="http://mywebsite.com"
    style="border:0px #ffffff none;"
    name="myiFrame"
    scrolling="no"
    frameborder="1"
    marginheight="0px"
    marginwidth="0px"
    height="400px"
    width="600px"
    allowfullscreen
></iframe>
```

Blogger shows the following warning:

> There are HTTP resources on this page, because of which mixed content can negatively affect the security and display of certain elements when viewing your blog over a secure connection.

How can I embed an iframe with HTTP URL into Blogspot.com?

Answer (score 0):

Blogger provides an option to **Dismiss** the warning. Refer to the screenshot -

[image: dismiss http mixed content warning]

Once that warning has been dismissed and you try to save the post once again, Blogger doesn't show any warning and saves the contents of the post.

Comment: I need only http in URL, not https.
If I dismiss this massage than iframe doesn't work.
Thank you.

Comment: An HTTP resource cannot open when the blog is accessed using HTTPS protocol because of *Mixed Content* error (Refer to https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content). If the blog is accessed via HTTP protocol, then the iframe should work